# Is it ok to use a 1500mAh battery when it calls for a 1100mAh

Tags: battery

The book for the Ge x600 says 3.7v 1100mAh but all I can find is 3.7v 1500mAh.  Can I use that in my GE x600 camera

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is okay to use a larger capacity battery in your camera. The only important value is the 3.7v specification.

There is a good chance the 1500mAh battery you want to buy is actually a 1100mAh because sellers and manufacturers often exaggerate the actual capacity.

Comment: And, notwithstanding the above-mentioned creative license manufacturers engage in, it's actually considered by most to be a good thing to find larger capacity batteries when you can. As long as the physical dimensions and the voltage match (and it's usually good to stick with the same technology too - NiCd vs Li Ion vs alkaline vs ......).

Comment: How are manufacturers coming up with specs that say 20000mAh when the real capacity is more like 500mAh? Are they rolling dice?

Comment: @xiota the mAh value is the summed up value of the cells. no transformation loses and other stuff are calculated in. also power banks say e.g. 20000mAh BUT this is the 3.7V value of the cells and not the value for the 5V USB connector. The mAh value overall is more or less pointless, because it depends on the voltage.